# Atualizar de forma dinâmica uma tabela primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-5.2

Olá, estou criando um cadastro em java com Primefaces. Tenho o seguinte problema:
tenho uma tela em xhtml e a mesma carrega os dados cadastrados, até aí tudo bem. O problema é quando alguém em outro computador estiver acessando ao mesmo tempo, não vai conseguir ver o novo cadastro que foi inserido, só vai conseguir ver se der F5 na página para atualizar. Alguém sabe como faço essa implementação de forma que esse problema seja resolvido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

você pode adicionar um evento que atualiza a tabela de tanto em tanto tempo.

```
<p:poll interval="10" listener="#{tabelaBean.carregarTabela}"
            update="idDaTabela"/>
```

com esta função, sua tabela vai ser atualizada de 10 em 10 segundos.

Comment: ok, Raphão Torres, estou com dificuldades em criar esse método "carregarTabela", estou vendo como faço por que estou aprendendo java tambem, desde  já muito obrigado

Comment: Boa noite consegui fazer funcionar, usei esse método public void carregarNomeDaClasse(){
  
  nomeDaClasseDAO nomeDaClasseDAO = new   nomeDaClasseDAO();
  nomedaclasse = nomedaclasseDAO.listar();   , usando na visão o <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{nomeDaClasseBean.carregarNomeDaClasse}" update="txt_count" />

Comment: no meu bean usei @ViewScoped. Mas agora me surgiu uma duvida, vi que ele vai ficar fazendo isso a cada 3 segundos, isso pode da uma sobrecargar no sevidor e fazer o mesmo para de responder?

Comment: que bom que conseguiu resolver.
Sim, você pode sobrecarregar o servidor.
Altere o intervalo para um tempo maior. Acredito que não tem outra forma de fazer...
Aqui na minha empresa temos um telão com o resultado de vendas que atualiza de 1 em 1 minuto. Mas no seu caso, acho que 20 segundos já fica bom. Abração!

Comment: Brigado  Raphão Torres